# Unable to connect to DB2 Database using java?

Tags: java, db2

I am trying to connect to a remote DB2 database located on a server. I have made the necessary DSN connection using ODBC and the test was successful. So in the below code i am using IMRM2 which is my DSN name, is that correct ?

But my main problem is i am getting the below error even after adding db2jcc.jar, db2jcc_license_cu.jar  to my eclipse library. ?

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at ConnectToDb2.makeConnection(CreateChart.java:19)
    at CreateChart.main(CreateChart.java:63)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
```

Java File.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class ConnectToDb2{

    String jdbcClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
    String url="jdbc:db2:IMRM2";
    String user="db2inst1";
    String password="DB2";
    Connection connection = null;


        public void makeConnection()
        {   

            try 
            {   
                Class.forName(jdbcClassName);
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            } 

            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            finally
            {
                if(connection!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Connected successfully.");
                    try 
                    {
                        connection.close();
                    }

                    catch (SQLException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }//End of finally 

        } // End of method makeConnection

}


public class CreateChart {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConnectToDb2 obj_connectdb2 = new ConnectToDb2();

        obj_connectdb2.makeConnection();

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your projects eclipse build path ?

Comment: "*java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)*" - looks like your driver's jar file is corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root issue is indicated in this line:

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Your driver file is likely corrupt.  If you use a zip program to open it, you may see errors indicated.

Solution: re-download your drivers.

Similar question, problem, and solution:
[tomcat7: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191900/tomcat7-could-not-load-jdbc-driver-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver/12215493#12215493)