# dyanmic project is not running on browser 404 is comming

Tags: java

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring/database/DataSource.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
```

Comment: Did you add the mysql driver jar?

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191900/tomcat7-could-not-load-jdbc-driver-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver